# Finding the equation for a (inverted) cycloid given two points

Tags: mathematical-physics, parametric, plane-curves, classical-mechanics, periodic-functions

If I have two points on a Cartesian plane, and I know that they are connected by a cycloid, then how do I find the equation for that cycloid?

For background information, I have been playing around with the brachistochrone problem, and I've found that the solution curve, an inverted cycloid, has parameters $x = \frac C2(t - \sin\;t)$ and $y = C - \frac C2(1 - \cos\;t)$, where $\frac C2$ is the radius of the rolling circle and $t$ is measured in radians.

Actually, I found $y = \frac C2(1 - \cos\;t)$; I would not know why the true solution would be an inverted cycloid as opposed to an upright one and how I would derive that from my calculations.

In any case, suppose we had two points, $(0,A)$ and $(B,0)$, where the former corresponds to the rolling circle having passed through an angle of $0$; the latter, an angle of $\pi$. The parametric equations for this example are then $x = \frac A2(t - \sin\;t)$ and $y = A - \frac A2(1 - \cos\;t)$.

Now suppose we have a similar pair of coordinates, specifically $(0,A)$ and $(2B,0)$. The angles corresponding to those angles are no longer $0$ and $\pi$. How would I then find the parametric equations for the curve connecting those two points?

Regards.

Comment: I don't recall the construction---I'm looking for it now---but the key is that the cycloid connecting them does _not_ have the lower point as the bottom of the cycloid: depending on the slope $2B/A$, it may be better for the endpoint to be a bit before or after the bottom of the cycloid...Ahah! Found a good [reference](http://whistleralley.com/brachistochrone/brachistochrone.htm). Take a look at the figure right before "Loose Ends."

Comment: To summarize that link: Draw an arbitrary cycloid along with the line connecting the two endpoints. The arc of the cycloid cut off by the line has the correct shape but wrong scale for the brachistochrone, so it just needs to be rescaled to actually connect the two endpoints.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help, and I understand how to resize the cycloid if the new point is on the same line connecting the original two points, but I'm having trouble understanding what to do if the new point is on a different line, such as in this case where the slope of the second line is 2B/A as opposed to B/A.

Answer (score 2):

I drew from the information provided by Semiclassical and Physicist137 (thank you for helping!) to draw out a direct solution to finding the curve connecting two points.

Suppose we wanted the cycloid connecting an initial, known point $A$ and a second, arbitrary point $B$. For simplicity, set $A=(0,0)$; a different initial point means a simple translation. Using the parametric equations,

\begin{array}{}
    x = a(t-\sin t) \\
    y = -a(1-\cos t),
  \end{array}

where $a$ is the unknown constant or the radius of the rolling circle, we can see that the slope connecting $A$ and $B$ is,

\begin{array}{}
    \frac yx = \frac{\cos t+1}{t-\sin t}.
  \end{array}

Notice that the slope is independent of the radius $a$. One unknown; one equation. In theory, we can then solve for $t$, $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$, and then use $t$ to solve for the unknown $a$. From there, you have your parametric equations that would describe the cycloid you're looking for.

To answer my note about the "inverted cycloid" and the inclusion of a negative sign, I realize that in my derivation of the brachistochrone curve, I had defined the $y$-direction -- for gravity -- to be positive downwards. Adjusting for the conventional Cartesian plane where $y$ downwards is negative, you would then swap the signs for $y$; $x$ is unaffected.

I suppose the next question to ask would be about the number of arches you could have connecting both points.

Answer (score 1):

A cycloid can also be interpreted the equation of motion of a point in a rolling-circle. You can check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) if you are not convinced. Or even prove it mathematically.

Therefore, you have two parameters: the radius of the circle $r$, and the angular speed of the circle $\omega$. The angle of the point in the circle is $t$. Then:

\begin{array}{}
    x = r(\omega t + \cos\omega t) \\
    y = r\sin\omega t
  \end{array}

Those equations are the rolling-circle I describe, in function of parameter $t$. I'm not sure if it is an cycloid or an inverted cycloid. But for your problem, I guess it is irrelevant.

Watching closely, we can notice that those equations are describing a circle $(\cos\omega t, \sin\omega t)$, but adding $r\omega t$ in the variable $x$, which says circle center is moving in $x$ direction with speed $r\omega$.

You can center the circle in arbitrary position $(x_0, y_0)$. Or you can define a initial position for the point in the circle. If you do so, you will get:

\begin{array}{}
    \Delta x = r(\omega t + \cos\omega \Delta t) \\
    \Delta y = r\sin\omega \Delta t
\end{array}

Now you have $r, \omega, x_0, y_0, t_0$ to chose. Fixing $r=1$, you would have to solve a system of 4 variables and 4 equations to get the solution to your problem.

Basically in your derivation, you just forgot that a point in a circle can rotate with $\omega$ different than 1.